# Regex in php, select everything after a part

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in which I only want the content after '### - '.

Example:

```
1234 - This is a string with 100 characters
```

I want to get this out of it: `This is a string with 100 characters`

I've been trying to get this for a few hours now, but I can't get it to work. I figured this code selected the numbers and the - sign: `#^\d+ - #` but I want the exact opposite part of the string.

Help is appreciated

Comment: You can encase substrings (sub groups) you want to extract with `( )`, and the special char `.` matches any character, so if you add `(.*)` to the end of your regex pattern, and then extract subgroup 1 you should get your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
~^\d+ - (.+)$~
```

And grab captured group #1

Or using **match reset** `\K`:

```
~^\d+ - \K.+$~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gU5oC3/1)

PS: You can also use your attempted regex in `preg_replace` like this:

```
$input = preg_replace('#^\d+ - #', '', $input);
```